# Copying data to excel sheet from mails using VB in outlook

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I receive hundreds of emails with this same format
[image]

I need to copy filename, status date, filesize, uploaded md5 and md5 on receiver to an excel sheet.

I have this code that copies filename, status date, filesize. But I need uploaded md5 and md5 on receiver values as well.

Could you please check my code and suggest changes to get uploaded md5 and md5 on receiver values?

Code:

```
Sub CopyToExcel()
Dim xlApp As Object
Dim xlWB As Object
Dim xlSheet As Object
Dim olItem As Outlook.MailItem
Dim vText As Variant
Dim sText As String
Dim vItem As Variant
Dim lineItems As Variant
Dim c As Long
Dim i As Long
Dim rCount As Long
Dim bXStarted As Boolean
Const strPath As String = "C:\Users\nhussain\Desktop\test.xlsx" 'the path of the workbook

If Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection.Count = 0 Then
  MsgBox "No Items selected!", vbCritical, "Error"
  Exit Sub
End If
On Error Resume Next
Set xlApp = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")
If Err <> 0 Then
    Application.StatusBar = "Please wait while Excel source is opened ... "
    Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    bXStarted = True
End If
On Error GoTo 0
'Open the workbook to input the data
Set xlWB = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(strPath)
Set xlSheet = xlWB.Sheets("Sheet1")

'Process each selected record
 rCount = xlSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
  For Each olItem In Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection
    sText = olItem.Body
    vText = Split(sText, Chr(13))
    'Find the next empty line of the worksheet
     rCount = rCount + 1
    'Check each line of text in the message body
    For i = UBound(vText) To 0 Step -1
      If InStr(1, vText(i), "File Name :") > 0 Then
            vItem = Split(vText(i), Chr(58))
            xlSheet.Range("A" & rCount) = Trim(vItem(1))
        End If

        If InStr(1, vText(i), "Status Date :") > 0 Then
            vItem = Split(vText(i), Chr(58))
            xlSheet.Range("B" & rCount) = Trim(vItem(1))
        End If

' Can't process 0-1 (zero minus 1) below so need to make sure we have i > 0
If i > 0 Then
    ' If the previous line contains "File Size" then this line is
    ' the file size, md5 and md5 received line
    If InStr(1, vText(i - 1), "File Size") > 0 Then
        ' Split the line by spaces
        lineItems = Split(Trim(vText(i)), " ")
        ' Populate the worksheet with the first item the size
        xlSheet.Range("C" & rCount) = Trim(lineItems(0)) & Trim(lineItems(1))
        lineItems = Split(Trim(vText(i)), Chr(9))

        ' Loop through each item in the array to get the rd5 values
        For c = 1 To UBound(lineItems, 1)
            ' Don't want blanks
            If lineItems(c) <> "" Then
                If xlSheet.Range("D" & rCount).Value2 = "" Then
                    xlSheet.Range("D" & rCount) = lineItems(c)
                Else
                    xlSheet.Range("E" & rCount) = lineItems(c)
                End If
            End If
        Next c
    End If
End If

    Next i
    xlWB.Save
Next olItem
xlWB.Close SaveChanges:=True
If bXStarted Then
    xlApp.Quit
End If
Set xlApp = Nothing
Set xlWB = Nothing
Set xlSheet = Nothing
Set olItem = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: The question you ask is a way too broad. You would need to write a VBA code that can analyze incoming emails and then parse the html code of that email to find the desired information. My advice: Start reading [Application.NewMail event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.application.newmail) and then do some further research. If you got started something on your own and you can come up with a more specific question come back here, show what you have tried and ask a question to it.

Comment: Have updated the code. If anyone can check and recommend where I am going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

It may be simpler to base the search on "bytes" rather than "File Size" so the line position is already known.

```
Option Explicit ' Consider this mandatory
' Tools | Options | Editor tab
' Require Variable Declaration
' If desperate declare as Variant

Private Sub CopyToExcel()

Dim xlApp As Object
Dim xlWB As Object
Dim xlSheet As Object

Dim xlDataArray() As String
ReDim xlDataArray(2)    ' zero based => 3 elements
Dim xlIndex As Long

Dim olItem As Object    ' Not all items are mailitems

Dim vText As Variant
Dim sText As String
Dim vItem As Variant
Dim lineItems As Variant

Dim i As Long
Dim j As Long

Dim rCount As Long
Dim bXStarted As Boolean

Const strPath As String = "C:\Users\nhussain\Desktop\test.xlsx" 'the path of the workbook

If ActiveExplorer.Selection.Count = 0 Then
    MsgBox "No Items selected!", vbCritical, "Error"
    Exit Sub
End If

On Error Resume Next
Set xlApp = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")
If Err <> 0 Then
    ' .StatusBar is not available in Outlook
    ' Error bypassed due to On Error Resume Next
    Application.StatusBar = "Please wait while Excel source is opened ... "
    Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    bXStarted = True
End If
On Error GoTo 0

'Open the workbook to input the data
Set xlWB = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(strPath)
Set xlSheet = xlWB.Sheets("Sheet1")
'xlApp.Visible = True

'Process each selected record
rCount = xlSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count

For Each olItem In ActiveExplorer.Selection

    If olItem.Class = olMail Then
    
        sText = olItem.Body
        'vText = Split(sText, Chr(13))
        vText = Split(sText, Chr(13) & Chr(10)) ' vbCrLf
        
        'Find the next empty line of the worksheet
        rCount = rCount + 1
        Debug.Print rCount
        
        'Check each line of text in the message body
        For i = LBound(vText) To UBound(vText)
                
            If Len(Trim(vText(i))) > 0 Then
            
                'Debug.Print i; vText(i)
                
                If InStr(1, vText(i), "File Name :") > 0 Then
                    vItem = Split(vText(i), Chr(58))
                    xlSheet.Range("A" & rCount) = Trim(vItem(1))
                End If
    
                If InStr(1, vText(i), "Status Date :") > 0 Then
                    vItem = Split(vText(i), Chr(58))
                    xlSheet.Range("B" & rCount) = Trim(vItem(1))
                    
                    Exit For
                    
                End If
            End If
        Next
            
        For i = UBound(vText) To LBound(vText) Step -1
                   
            If InStr(1, vText(i), "bytes") > 0 Then
 
                Debug.Print Trim(vText(i))
                lineItems = Split(Trim(vText(i)), " ")
                    
                xlIndex = 0
                    
                For j = LBound(lineItems) To UBound(lineItems)
                    If Len(lineItems(j)) > 0 Then
                        Debug.Print xlIndex; lineItems(j)
                        If lineItems(j) <> "bytes" Then
                            xlDataArray(xlIndex) = lineItems(j)
                            Debug.Print xlIndex; xlDataArray(xlIndex)
                            xlIndex = xlIndex + 1
                        End If
                    End If
                Next
                
                Exit For
                    
            End If
        Next i
                   
        ' Populate the worksheet
        xlSheet.Range("C" & rCount) = xlDataArray(0)
        xlSheet.Range("D" & rCount) = xlDataArray(1)
        xlSheet.Range("E" & rCount) = xlDataArray(2)
    
        xlWB.Save
        
    End If
    
Next olItem

xlSheet.Columns.AutoFit

xlWB.Close SaveChanges:=True
If bXStarted Then
    xlApp.Quit
End If

Set xlApp = Nothing
Set xlWB = Nothing
Set xlSheet = Nothing
Set olItem = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: This code doesnt execute on outlook. I can add it as a module on VB. But doesnt appear in the developer tab.

Comment: To check code for unwanted behaviour put your cursor on a line and step through with F8 (see Debug menu). You can run with F5 (see Run menu) or toolbar button. Multiple versions of code with the same name will generate ambiguous name messages. Buttons will no longer run assigned code until you decide. This is common on my machine unless I address the issue by changing the name or using `Private`. Remove `Private`.